# What happens when I remove unretained objects from an NSMutableSet

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSMutableSet of sprites which are each declared thusly:

```
SpriteEntity * newProjectile = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"tiles.png" rect:CGRectMake(48,0,16,16)];
```

Now, these are stored in an NSMutableSet which is retained (created by calling alloc and init). When I call removeObject on one of the SpriteEntities, what happens to it?

I would assume that garbage collection gets them, but I would like to know for sure.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you test this? Create an NSMutableSet, add three SpriteEntity objects, retain one and not the other and keep one as default, and then remove them one at a time, with an NSLog between.

Comment: So, you need to be very clear here, if you  are using Garbage Collection (GC), manual reference counting (MRC) or Automatic Reference Counting (ARC). GC does not use retain & release the same way. The GC mechanism will periodically run (unless invoked) to clean things up, and not necessarily in the same cycles as reference counting & dealloc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing an object from a collection drops its reference count by one. If no other reference points to the object, then its reference count reaches 0 and it is deallocated.

Comment: It is deallocated at the end of the current cycle. It can still be used during the "current" cycle but it's not good practice.

Comment: @PaulArdeleanu Right, but that's an implementation detail. One must always think of collection members as being available only as long as they are in the collection (or retained before having been removed).

Comment: Absolutely correct. Only wanted to make sure that he gets the whole idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the CCSprite class uses standard naming conventions, that method does not increase the reference count of the object it instantiates; therefor, the object's only owner is the NSMutableSet. Once the object has been removed from that set, the reference count is decreased by one, making it zero, and therefor queuing the object for deallocation.